# What is avalara's Landed Cost API Live URL?

Tags: php, magento, avalara

I am using http://sandbox.landedcost.api.avalara.com/v3/calculate for calculating avlara landed cost in our test environment. Now we are going Live and we need to change this sandbox URL to a live one. But the replacement for this API url is not found anywhere in the blogs or support documents. Does anybody know about this?

Thanks and regards,
Manaf

Answer (score -1):

Its a "API solutions for end-to-end tax compliance". you can check this url: https://developer.avalara.com/avalara-apis/ for more information.